# How to create transition with css of text that scrolls in from right and out in left and starts over again without LAG

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to animate my dashboard with a scrolling text in the footer at the bottom of the screen. Have almost succeeded with some CSS and an absolute position, but it "lags" sometimes, and it's on every computer/screen I tested it on.

How it should work, is that text will scroll in from right side, and scroll out of the screen in the left side.

**Css code**

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7rem;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    color: black;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(217, 217, 217, .5);
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

.footer .footer-text {
    vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color:black;
    font-size: 2.7em;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-animation: anim 25.5s infinite;
    animation: anim 25.5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
    from {
        right: -300%;
    }
    to {
        right: 100%;
    }
}

@keyframes anim {
   from {
         right: -300%;
   }
   to {
       right: 100%;
   }
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-text">
        <span>Some scrolling text here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works, but it lags quite often when it runs, you can see the text is not smooth. Tested in Chrome and Firefox (Chrome will be the primary browser where the application will run)

Any possible fix to this, or is it just not possible with css to make these kind of animation?

Btw, I'm using Angular

Hope someone can comment on a possible direction/fix ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS `transform` instead of changing the positioning reference causes the browser to check for page reflows and is very inefficient.

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
    from {
        transform: translateX(300%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes anim {
   from {
         transform: translateX(300%);
   }
   to {
       transform: translateX(0);
   }
}
```